# how to increase the amount of time for recording speech in android using RecogniserIntent?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

Since,
EXTRA_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS or EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS 
no longer work, are there any other alternatives?